# Распарсить текст в bash и записать в cтроку

Tags: linux, bash, join, sed, awk

```
test-1.me:010203(tcp) 0
test-2.me:030201(tcp) 0
test-3.not.me:010203(udp) 256
test-4.maybe.me:030201(udp) 0
test-5.who.is.me:010203(tcp) 65280
test-6.me:030201(tcp) -1
```

Есть файл с примерно таким содержимым. Нужно как-то распарсить его, чтоб на выходе получить в одной строке через запятую всё, где нет в конце одного 0. То есть в данном конкретном случае будет `RESULT IS: test-3.not.me:010203(udp),test-5.who.is.me:010203(tcp),test-6.me:030201(tcp)`.

Пока написал регулярку `^.*(?<!\s0{1})$` https://regex101.com/r/NkXFwP/1 которая почему-то работает на regex101, но не хочет в grep/egrep :) Был бы признателен, если б мне подсказали решение с использованием sed/awk/join и т.п. стандартных утилит. Я бы мог сделать это на python, к примеру, но мне кажется, это то же самое что по гвозди отвёрткой забивать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `awk`/`sed`:

```
result="RESULT IS: $(awk '!/ 0$/{print $1}' ORS="," <<< "$text" | sed 's/,$//')"
# Или ещё вариант
# result="RESULT IS: $(awk '$2!=0{print $1}' ORS="," <<< "$text" | sed 's/,$//')"
echo "$result"
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/WOQoxh):

```
text="test-1.me:010203(tcp) 0
test-2.me:030201(tcp) 0
test-3.not.me:010203(udp) 256
test-4.maybe.me:030201(udp) 0
test-5.who.is.me:010203(tcp) 65280
test-6.me:030201(tcp) 65280"

result="RESULT IS: $(awk '!/ 0$/{print $1}' ORS="," <<< "$text" | sed 's/,$//')"
echo "$result"
# => RESULT IS: test-3.not.me:010203(udp),test-5.who.is.me:010203(tcp),test-6.me:030201(tcp)
```

**Подробности**

- `awk '!/ 0$/{print $1}' ORS="," file` - в файле file ищет все строки, не заканчивающиеся на пробел + 0, берёт только первый элемент ("поле", `{print $1}`) и собирает их в одну строку через запятую (`ORS=","` задаёт разделитель)
- Если испльзовать `$2!=0`, происходит проверка на равенство значения во втором поле нулю
- `sed 's/,$//'` удаляет лишнюю запятую в конце.

Comment: Отлично, но нужно без второго аргумента строку формировать) Ну, то есть, без  `256,  65280` и .т.п)

Comment: @whoknow без второго аргумента так - `awk '!/ $0/ {print $1}' ORS="," file | sed 's/,$//'` - опережу автора ответа ))

Comment: О, замечательно, а я `print $1` после указания файла писАл, и он ошибкой ругался, теперь понятно куда надо было вписывать)

Comment: А как-то можно через тот же `awk` без конвееров спереди подставить `RESULT IS: ` ?

Comment: Я  обновил ответ.

Comment: А почему вот такая конструкция не работает? `awk '$2~!/ 0$/{b+=$1}END{ print "RESULT IS: "b}' /my/file.txt`

Comment: Так у вас во втором поле нет пробела, а вы его указываете в регулярном выражении.

Comment: Ага, ошибка, но даже если убрать пробел - ничего не изменяется...

Comment: Вы хотите избавиться от `sed`а, чтобы убрать запятую в конце строки в `awk`?

Comment: Не-е-е, для меня не принципиальна запятая в конце, пусть их там хоть 2 будет. Ваш вариант хороший, просто я теперь хочу понять почему мой не работает, лишь ради академического интереса :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94903/discussion-between-who-know-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: В `awk` нужно объединять строки с помощью `b=b ORS $1`. `awk '$2!=0 {b=b ORS $1} END { print "RESULT IS: "b}' ORS="," <<< "$text" | sed 's/^,//'` [сработает](https://ideone.com/CCEka9).